# Session Attributes [ AWS Lambda / Amazon Alexa Skill]

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-slot

I am using sessionAttributes to access slot values in every function in my Lambda function and have to copy paste this line basically in every func (**session_attr = handler_input.attributes_manager.session_attributes**) What would be the most elegant way to state it so it does not need to be copy pasted.
Thanks for help!

@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("MyCityIntent"))
def my_city_handler(handler_input):

```
# type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
intent_name = intnt_name(handler_input)

**session_attr = handler_input.attributes_manager.session_attributes**
slots = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots
```

Comment: If you want to access those JSON values, I don't see any other easy way. If you want to parse some large JSON data, you could look into using Lambda layers to set up a common JSON parsing function which can be used across multiple Lambda functions.

Comment: yes, for accessing JSON. Thanks for ur reply!